# Show the clicking visual effect of a JButton inside a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcombobox

I have created a `JComboBox` with a custom `ListCellRenderer` (a `JButton`) as below:

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("One");
JButton b2 = new JButton("Two");
JButton b3 = new JButton("Three");

JButton[] buttonList = {b1, b2, b3};

JComboBox box = new JComboBox(buttonList);
box.setRenderer(new CellRenderer());
//...


/**************** Custom Cell Renderer Class ****************/
class CellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,
                boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {            
            JButton button = (JButton) value;
            return button;           
}
```

I have set button actions separately and all are works fine except when I am clicking 
a button from the combo box it doesn't shows the button clicking visual effect.

How to show the clicking visual effect of a `JButton` inside a `JComboBox`?

Comment: 1) I think you'll find those buttons do not act as `ActionListener` instances.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14426821/230513).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason for not showing the visual clicking effects inside a JComboBox From this --> [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098521/how-to-put-a-jbutton-inside-a-jcombobox)